# Evaluating series expansion is very slow

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, series-expansion, expression-manipulation

I need in my work to get series expansion of

```
(2 E^x x HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + E^-x/4, 1 + E^-x/4}, -(x^2/4)])/Gamma[E^-x/2] + x^(1 - E^-x/2) Sin[x]
```

up to $n=20$. I have tried to run

```
Normal[Series[(2 E^x x HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + E^-x/4, 1 + E^-x/4}, -(x^2/4)])/Gamma[E^-x/2] + x^(1 - E^-x/2) Sin[x], {x, 0, n}]]
```

The problem is that time consumed to get the expansion at $n=13$ is about 9 minutes, and I waited for hours to evaluate at $n=20$ and failed to get a result.

Is there alternative algorithm I may use (or code it myself) to get the result I need?

Comment: What version are you running?  I just ran for `n = 13` and it took about a minute on 13.3.1

Comment: Likewise. Took around 18 minutes for n=17.

Comment: Did you write your expressions correctly as `E^-x/2` and `E^-x/4` or should it be rather `E^(-x/2)` and `E^(-x/4)`?

Answer (score 5):

For  alternative algorithm and for **speed up** you can may use: **NSeries**:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];

f[x_] := (2 E^x x HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + E^-x/4, 1 + E^-x/4}, -(x^2/4)])/Gamma[E^-x/2] + x^(1 - E^-x/2) Sin[x];

A = NSeries[f[x], {x, 0, 11}, WorkingPrecision -> 100] // Chop // Normal;
N[A /. x -> 1, 30]
(*1.53958275073140462980687669621 - 0.01188149961898482687275300695 I*)

B = Series[f[x], {x, 0, 11}] // Normal;
N[B /. x -> 1, 20]
(*1.5365816625602003563*)

N[f[1], 20]
(*1.5366773917420970181*)
```

**Probably** for greater **precision** you must give more **terms**.

Answer (score 5):

One can try breaking the expression into pieces:

```
expr = (2 E^x x HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + E^-x/4, 1 + E^-x/4}, -(x^2/4)])/Gamma[E^-x/2] 
        + x^(1 - E^-x/2) Sin[x]
slow[n_] := Normal[Series[expr, {x, 0, n}]]
fast[n_] := Module[{num, den, res},
      num = Series[(2 E^x x HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + E^-x/4, 1 + E^-x/4}, -(x^2/4)]), {x, 0, n}];
      den = Series[Gamma[E^-x/2], {x, 0, n}];
      res = Normal[Series[num/den, {x, 0, n}]] + Normal[Series[x^(1 - E^-x/2) Sin[x], {x, 0, n}]];
      res
                  ];
```

Check:

```
    Module[{n = 10, f, s},
      f = AbsoluteTiming[fast[#]] & /@ Range[n];
      s = AbsoluteTiming[slow[#]] & /@ Range[n];
      TableForm[Transpose[{Range[n], f[[All, 1]], s[[All, 1]], 
         Simplify[f[[All, 2]] - s[[All, 2]], Assumptions -> {x > 0}] }], 
         TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "Elapsed fast", "Elapsed slow", "Diff"}}
               ]
          ]

fast[13]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {3.74571, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note, imo, is that the second term of the expression has a branch cut from $0$ to $-\infty$.

```
FunctionProperties`LocallyHolomorphicQ[x^(1 - E^-x/2) Sin[x], x, 0]

(* False *)

FunctionAnalytic[{x^(1 - E^-x/2) Sin[x], Abs[x] < 1/10}, x, Complexes]

(* False *)
```

It has neither a power nor a Laurent series; rather, its series is a mix of logarithms and square-roots. However, the series is rather quick to compute:

```
ser2 = Series[x^(1 - E^-x/2) Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.124933, Null} *)

(* x^(11/2) term has a "coefficient" that is a polynomial in Log[x] *)
SeriesCoefficient[ser2, 11/2] 

(* (16 + 40 Log[x] + 100 Log[x]^2 - 60 Log[x]^3 + 5 Log[x]^4)/1920 *)
```

For the first term, one can use `NSeries` (as @Mariusz did, but with just the first term). Or you can use the Cauchy integral formula:

```
f = (2 E^x x HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + E^-x/4, 
            1 + E^-x/4}, -(x^2/4)])/Gamma[E^-x/2];
ser1 = Table[
       1/(2 Pi I)
         NIntegrate[(f Dt[x, t])/x^(n + 1) /. x -> Exp[I t]/10, {t, 0,
           2 Pi}, Method -> "Trapezoidal", WorkingPrecision -> 32, 
         AccuracyGoal -> 20],
       {n, 0, 20}
      ] // Chop[#, 10^-20] & // 
    SeriesData[x, 0, #, 0, Length@#, 1] &; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.255677, Null} *)
```

Check the error:

```
(2 E^x x HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1/2 + E^-x/4, 
       1 + E^-x/4}, -(x^2/4)])/Gamma[E^-x/2] + 
  x^(1 - E^-x/2) Sin[x] /.
 {{x -> 1.`32}, {x -> 1/10.`32}, {x -> 1/100.`32}}

(* {1.5366773917420970181216583991955, 
    0.14088996522100268533174538168929, 
    0.012262740086836606574087812170464} *)

Normal[ser1 + ser2] /. x -> {1.`32, 1/10.`32, 1/100.`32}

(* {1.5366774115402366219656862403643, 
    0.14088996522100268533174556092222, 
    0.012262740086836606574087812170464} *)

% - %% // N

(* {1.97981*10^-8, 1.79233*10^-25, 0.} *)
```